# How to find a form from many forms in vb6 on a existing project

Tags: sql, forms, debugging, vb6

I am working on a old project of vb6 which has hundreds if forms. I am able to run the application and have to fix a runtime error in a form which pop up. I don't know the name of the form and only have visual reference. I tried using debug but It has continues SQL statements running in a loop. Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search the code for the form caption, or the labels of controls on the form, using visual studio's "find in files" or simlar function of your favourite editor.

- If the caption is set in the form design, this will take you to the `.frm` file the form is stored in. You can open this in Notepad or another editor to get the name of the class (which is usually the same as the filename).
- If the caption is set in code, you can place a breakpoint on that line. Again, this will lead you to the code which instantiates the form.

Comment: Thank you. It works. I also used find and replace by searching with the text that I see on labels in run time also helped me find the form.